# Angular 4 directive to manipulate input text

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have created a simple directive to trim my input text (I plan to expand it's functionality later - so please don't recommend a simple onkeyup function), I would like to make a directive work.

I use my directive like this:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" inputTextFilter [(ngModel)]="data.name">
```

and my directive is as follows:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[inputTextFilter]'
})

export class InputTextFilterDirective {
  value: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('contrusted InputTextFilterDirective');
    this.value = '';
  }

  @HostListener('change')
  onChange($event) {
    console.log('in change InputTextFilterDirective');
    this.value = $event.target.value.trim();
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

I see the constructor message log to the window, but the on change message never appears, and my value never changes (spaces aren't trimmed from end).  I suspect hostListeners and hostProperties aren't right as I've seen lots of conflicting examples...but can't confirm a right way.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You are probably looking for a pipe. You would have to decouple the ngModel into `[ngModel]="data.name | trimPipe" (ngModel)="data.name=$event"`

Comment: I see your point - I'll play with pipe after, but for now I think a directive should work...just can't figure out how

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your directive to

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[inputTextFilter]'
})

export class InputTextFilterDirective {
  @Input() ngModel: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log('constructed InputTextFilterDirective');
    (el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value = '';
  }

  @HostListener('change')
  onChange() {
    console.log('in change InputTextFilterDirective');
    (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();
    console.log(this.ngModel);
  }
}
```

Try and see if that works. If it didn't, try changing the event from '`change`' to '`input`' or '`ngModelChange`'

Comment: The change event triggers when leaving the field, but the value does not update (trimmed)

Comment: try changing it to `ngModelChange` event (or `input` event as mentioned at the bottom of my answer)

Comment: I got it to work with the following, but it seems a bit complex: (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value = (this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();

Comment: As long as you are planning to reuse your directive on an `input` element this will work. What other cases would you expect a value to be trimmed?

Comment: I'm not sure - this was more theoritical (how to do) than practical.  I'm now working on a pipe to do what I want as Ploppy suggested above.

Comment: `@HostListener('input')  onChange() { ... }` did the trick, I am finally able to remove Spacing diaeresis - umlaut `¨` from the input. It is somehow impossible to block it from user input. By typing ¨ it allows user to enter any other symbol such as & (, etc. It is quite weird.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[trim-text]'
})
export class TrimTextDirective {
    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
    ) {}

    @HostListener('blur')
    // @HostListener('input')
    @HostListener('change')
    applyTrim() {
        let ele = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
        if (typeof ele.value === 'string') {
            ele.value = ele.value.trim();
        }
    }
}
```

If you uncomment "@HostListener('input')" you wont be able to write spaces (in case you want to trim the sides and allow having spaces in between)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this directive created by me:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-trim-directive

It lies on a very simple fact that Angular listens to input event to bring the view-to-model binding into being.